# Recursively strip vowels from a String

Tags: scala, recursion

I would like to know why this gives a compilation error, and how I would correct it:

```
def stripVowelsRecursive(str: String): Char = {
if(str.length() == 0) ' '
else
   for(ch <- str) {
      if(isVowel(ch)) ch
      else ' ' +stripVowelsRecursive(str.tail)
   }
}
```

The Scala workbench worksheet complains about the for loop being of type `Unit`, whereas it expected a `Char`.

BTW, I would have written it this way, but I need to understand what I am doing wrong for the above specifically, as both branches of the `if` statement return a Char:

```
def stripoutVowels(str: String) = for (ch <- str if(isVowel(ch))) yield ch
```

Comment: You forgot `yield` before `if`

Comment: This function looks a bit weird. You're passing a string in, to strip its vowels and you're expecting a Char as a result? Could you please elaborate what you are after?

Comment: "both branches of the if statement return a Char:" ... which is then discarded, because a `for` without `yield` returns... (you guessed it) `Unit`. Hence the worksheet's error. As @Kolmar said, a yield is required

Comment: I think my question is not well formed. for sure. I apologize. My only excuse is that I am a Scala newbie. So I thank all the contributors. I will pour over the answers and learn from it. thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Troubles in your code:

1. as Kolmar mentioned missing `yield` after `for`
2. `a + b` if both `a` and `b` are chars results to `Int` in Java\Scala, not to concatenated strings
3. You are trying to mix explicit `for` loop and recursion in your `else`, you must choose one

possible solutions:

```
def stripVowelsRecursive(str: String): String =
  if (str.isEmpty) ""
  else (if (isVowel(str.head)) str.head else "") + stripVowelsRecursive(str.tail)

def stripVowelsRecursiveOpt(str: String): String = {
  def go(acc: List[Char], chars: Seq[Char]): String = chars match {
    case ch +: rest if isVowel(ch) => go(acc, rest)
    case ch +: rest => go(ch :: acc, rest)
    case Nil => acc.reverse.mkString
  }
  go(Nil, str)
}

def stripVowelsLoop(str: String): String = for (ch <- str if isVowel(ch)) yield ch

def stripVowelsSimples(str: String): String = str.filter(isVowel)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you're trying to do. The problem is that you're trying to loop in your algorithm instead of leaving the recursion to do the loop for you. Have a look at this:

```
  def stripVowelsRecursive(str: String): String = {
    if (str.length == 0) ""
    else {
      if (isVowel(str.head)) " " + stripVowelsRecursive(str.tail)
      else str.head.toString + stripVowelsRecursive(str.tail)
    }
  }
```

- The return type must change from `Char` to `String` so you can call the function recursively with the `tail` of the String.
- The recursive path needs to evaluate the String's `head` and apply recursion to its `tail`.
- Not sure why you were creating another blank string in your base case. Changed it to empty string

Comment: Thank you that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score -1):

It is because your else does not returns a char, but a `Unit`. A method with return type `Unit` is analogous to a Java method which is declared `void`. The `if` and `else` both returns chars, but the `for` loops doesn't, and that is your problem. Besides that, your `else` block is returning a `String` and not a `Char` since `String.tail` returns a `String` and `Char + String` results in a `String`.

A proper solution using just recursion would be:

```
def stripVowelsRecursive(str: String): String = {
  if (str.length() == 0) str
  else {
    val head: Char = str.head
    val tail: String = str.tail

    if(isVowel(head)) stripVowelsRecursive(tail)
    else head + stripVowelsRecursive(tail)
  }
}
```

The second example (with `yield`) works because it is a [sequence comprehensions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/sequence-comprehensions.html) instead and it is the `yield` blocks that is responsible to return the value, not the `for` or the `if`.